# How to set Django model attribute based on another attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model which takes time into account. So when I set is_all_day as True I want my start_hour and end_hour to return 6:00 and 23:59 respectively but it returns null. 
This is my model:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    start_hour = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_hour = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_all_day = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'test_model'

    def start_all_day(self):
        if self.is_all_day == 'True':
            self.start_hour = '6:00'
            self.start_hour.save()
            return self.start_hour
        else:
            return self.start_hour

    def end_all_day(self):
        if self.is_all_day == 'True':
            self.end_hour = '23:59'
            self.end_hour.save()
            return self.end_hour
        else:
            return self.start_hour
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should somehow call these functions (in your views function, for ex.) or in `save` method

Answer (score 4):

As @Andy mentioned, you can override the save() method of the model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Override start_hour and end_hour if is_all_day is True"""
    if self.is_all_day:
        self.start_hour = '6:00'
        self.end_hour = '23:59'
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or you can also use @properties to achieve something similar:

```
@property
def begin(self):
    return '6:00' if self.is_all_day else self.start_hour

@property
def end(self):
    return '23:59' if self.is_all_day else self.end_hour
```

*Please change the code above to always handle same type of time or string.*